# Preciso de um if que altere a mascara de uma input

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, mysql

Olá , eu tenho um código php mysql, e preciso de ajuda, o código já está pronto só falta a opção de editar os dados, é nisso que eu preciso de ajuda, vou explicar oque está acontecendo, eu tenho meu código ele tem três inputs, a primeira pede oque será editado a segunda pedi o novo valor e a terceira onde está esse valor, todas estão prontas porém eu gostaria de saber se tem algum jeito de após eu colocar oque será editado ele colocar uma mascara no novo valor ex:
oque será editado?: CEP

Novo valor: 89212-530 (observe o traço é isso que eu quero, mas eu quero que ele só apareça se o primeiro dado seja cep)
onde: clientes
OBS: Eu estou usando um plugin jquery para as mascaras (jquery maskedinput)

```html
<form action="editar.php" method="POST" class="envio_de_dados3 panel panel-default">
    <h4 class="panel-heading ">Cpf da Pesssoa cujo registro será alterado</h4><input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" id="cpf2" name="edit"><br>
    <h4 class="panel-heading ">Oque será editado</h4><input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" id="WE" name="editt"><br>
    <h4 class="panel-heading ">Novo Valor</h4><input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" name="editado"><br><br>
    <input type="submit"><br>
</form>
```

Comment: Se a resposta ajudou, marque como solução ;)

Comment: ajudou um pouco porém oque eu queria é que quando você mandasse ao servidor que o valor que você quer editar é o cep ele colocaria uma mascara no novo valor da variavel cep, mas só se o valor que vai ser editado seja o cep se não for eu não quero que a máscara apareça. entendeu? kk

Comment: Entendi, aplicar apenas em CEP certo?

Comment: Não é mais fácil adicionar um novo campo com o nome CEP ? Ai a pessoa só vai digitar o CEP

Comment: eu vou fazer de outro jeito, obrigado pela ajuda Victor vou marcar sua resposta como certa afinal você foi o unico que tentou ajudar, obrigado por isso  :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usando `JavaScript`, é bem simples e aumenta a usabilidade de um formulário.

Por exemplo, em um cadastro com vários campos, uma pessoa não vai perder tempo pausando a digitação dos números para colocar traços ou também, para a correção dos dados já que fica bem mais organizado.

Estruta do Código `JavaScript e HTML`:

```js
 function mascara(t, mask){
 var i = t.value.length;
 var saida = mask.substring(1,0);
 var texto = mask.substring(i)
 if (texto.substring(0,1) != saida){
 t.value += texto.substring(0,1);
 }
 }
```

```html
<form name="cadatro">
 <table width="500px" align="center">
 <tr>
 <td width="100px">
 <b>CEP:</b>
  </td>
 <td>
 <input type="text" name="cep" onkeypress="mascara(this, '#####-###')" maxlength="9">
 </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td>
 <b>Telefone:</b>
 </td>
 <td>
 <input type="text" name="telefone" onkeypress="mascara(this, '## ####-####')" maxlength="12">
 </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td>
 <b>Celular:</b>
 </td>
 <td>
 <input type="text" name="celular" onkeypress="mascara(this, '## #####-####')" maxlength="13">
 </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td colspan="2">
 <input type="submit" value="Enviar">
 <input type="reset" value="Limpar">
 </td>
 </tr>
 </table>
 </form>
```

Caso queira usar também para CPF, RG, etc... basta apenas mudar as posições e os caracteres dessa parte `onkeypress="mascara(this, '## #####-####')"`

Para CPF:

```
 <input type="text" name="cpf" onkeypress="mascara(this, '###.###.###-##')" maxlength="9">
```